# Install user specific onEdit Trigger using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on

I have created a simple OnOpen add-on in Google sheets that installs a trigger to send email based on Edit in the sheet. When I installed it, I authorized it from my account. The script is as follows:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Install Trigger").addItem("Run", "initialize").addToUi();
 }
 
const initialize = () => {
  
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
     ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
     .onEdit()
     .create();
};
```

The script runs fine and sends emails from my email address which I authorized. Now the issue is when I shared this sheet with another editor, the person does not need to install this trigger and he can send email from my email account without any authorization. Is there a way that we can make every editor in this sheet install their own trigger to send email from their email account instead of using mine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method [getUserTriggers(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app?hl=en#getusertriggersspreadsheet) that retrieves all installable triggers owned by the user executing the script:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
// Log the event type for the first trigger in the array.
Logger.log(triggers[0].getEventType());
```

If this comes with a trigger, you know that the user has already installed the trigger.

If this comes empty, means that the user has no triggers in it. Then you could use the method [deleteTrigger(trigger)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app?hl=en#deletetriggertrigger) to delete the existing triggers (created by others) in the script and then programatically create a new one:

```js
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
```

Comment: But I just want the users to use their own trigger installed by them instead of using mine. I do not want to delete any trigger.

Comment: You could make them create only the new trigger, but if the project is shared then it will have as many triggers as users have. Another option could be creating a copy of the sheet and script without any trigger and give each user a copy, but if the sheet is updated for everyone this would not work.